# I can see the expanded usercards with my current reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I've just realized that I can see the expanded usercards. According to SF's privilege model I shouldn't be able to. Have you changed some rules and forgot to reflect them to the privilege page or is there something wrong with the site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not very clear but the privilege relates to *your* usercard which will expand once you reach the [Established User](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/established-user) milestone providing other conditions are met.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243523/146257 Thanks to you, too. I've just realized what this privilege means.